# iOS YouTube "No Filters Selected"

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

I'm trying to make a request for playListItems using the YouTube iOS SDK.

I'm getting back an error...

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain
Code=-32602 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (No filter selected.)" 
UserInfo=0x1568f1e0
{
    error=No filter selected.,
    GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x1567fdf0: {message:"No filter selected." code:-32602 data:[1]},
    NSLocalizedFailureReason=(No filter selected.)
}
```

The query I'm using is this...

```
GTLServiceYouTube *service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];

service.APIKey = @"my key";

// I suspect the problem is here...
GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"contentDetails"];
query.q = @"playlistId=<The playlist ID>";

GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                                   if (!error) {
                                       GTLYouTubePlaylistItemListResponse *playlistItems = object;

                                       for (GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *playlistItem in playlistItems) {
                                           GTLYouTubePlaylistItemContentDetails *details = playlistItem.contentDetails;

                                           NSLog(@"PlaylistItem video ID = %@", details.videoId);
                                       }
                                   } else {
                                       NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                   }
                               }];
```

The problem is that the docs for the entire API are useless so there is no example of this being used. I'm having to put it together from the example for the Google Shopping apis and stuff.

Most of the guess work came from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list).

Any ideas what I should put in the `query.q` value? Or if there's something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally found a link that shed some link on this.

The code to use is...

```
query.playlistId = @"the playlist ID";
```

Then everything worked :D